# Cannot create instance for an interface while using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-interop

I want to convert Word document to pdf. For that I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. I am using this in both language C# as well VB.NET

I am loading `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` from GAC during runtime. Assembly is getting loaded in runtime even I am getting classes and by using Type.

For methods, I am using `MethodInfo`.

Issue comes when I am trying to create instance using `Activator.CreateInstance` it gives an error **Cannot create  instance for an interface.**

I am using two classes i.e documents and application. But when I saw their definition interface was implemented.

[image: Code Added in image]

Comment: Please provide the code as text in the body of the question.  A picture of the code is not an adequate substitute.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* just add a reference to the interop library and use it normally:

[image: Dialog to add a reference]

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

The above is how I would recommend doing things. To answer your question, though, I suspect you might be able to do it your way if you try:

```
Type wordApp = assWord.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass");
```